# UILabel how to tighten letter spacing

Tags: ios, uilabel

I would like to know how to programatically "Tighten Letter Spacing"?

This option is available for a UILabel made in a xib file, and is really handy sometimes.

I know this question has been asked before, but I don't see an answer that mentions this beeing available in the interface builder, so I was curious...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth
```

Property of `UILabel` new in `iOS6`.

Comment: Thank you!Would upvote you if I could. Too bad it's not available in iOS 5,

Answer (score 8):

You might want to use UILabel property:

```
allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation: Bool
```

and set it to `true`. (Default is `false`)

According to Apple Documentation:

> When this property is set to true, the label tightens intercharacter spacing of its text before allowing any truncation to occur. The label determines the maximum amount of tightening automatically based on the font, current line width, line break mode, and other relevant information.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620533-allowsdefaulttighteningfortrunca

Answer (score 5):

`adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth) as of iOS 7.

You'd now (as of iOS 8) probably want to do something like:

```
NSAttributedString *as = 
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Kerninating all the strings"
                                attributes:@{NSKernAttributeName : @(-2.0)}];
label.attributedText = as;
```